# How do I know if an Google App Engine instance is Standard or Flexible?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google App Engine has two flavors:

[image]

Give a running App Engine instance, is there a way to know through the UI if it is standard or flexible? If not, what other ways of figuring out are there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check it selecting the App Engine tab in the left side and the clicking on Versions.

> App Engine > Versions

You will see several information about the service, among other things the runtime where it is running. Will be it `Standard` or `Flexible`.

Also note that a service can have more than 1 instance spawned. It is the service which is defined to run on the `Standard` or `Flexible` environment.